# Make new pandas table based on existing table, without modifying existing table

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing pandas table with 5 columns. I want to make a new table that is basically the same thing as the existing table, but with only 2 of the 5 columns in the existing table.

Using drop modifies the existing table, which I don't want to do. Any suggestions of what I should use instead of drop?

Comment: You can just slice the columns. `new_df = original_df[['col1', 'col2']]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a slice with the columns you need:

```
import pandas as pd

original = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']])

extract = original.ix[:, 1:2]
```

(here we get the 2nd and 3rd columns)